# Gnuplot fit error - singular matrix in Givens()

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

So I want to fit a function with a dataset using gnuplot. In the file "cn20x2012", at the lines [1:300] I have this data:

```html
1   -7.576723949519277e-06
2   4.738414366971162e-05
3   2.5908117324519247e-05
4   7.233786749999952e-06
5   4.94720225240387e-06
6   -1.857620375000113e-06
7   5.697280584855734e-06
8   -1.867760712716345e-05
9   6.64096591257211e-05
10  2.756199717307687e-05
11  4.7755705550480866e-05
12  6.590865376225963e-05
13  4.1522206877403805e-05
14  3.145294946394234e-05
15  5.9346948090625035e-05
16  5.405458204471163e-05
17  0.0001484469089218749
18  0.00011236895265264405
19  0.00010798644697620197
20  8.656723035552881e-05
21  0.00019917737876442313
22  0.00022625750686778835
23  0.00023183354141658626
24  0.0003373178915148073
25  0.00032313619574999994
26  0.0003451188893915866
27  0.0003303809005983172
28  0.0003534148565745192
29  0.00039690566743750015
30  0.0004182810016802884
31  0.00045198626877403865
32  0.00047311462195192373
33  0.0004962054400408655
34  0.0004969566757524037
35  0.0005561838221274039
36  0.0005353567324539659
37  0.00052834133201923
38  0.0005980226227637016
39  0.0005446277144831731
40  0.0005960780049278846
41  0.0006076488594567314
42  0.000710219997610289
43  0.0006714079307259616
44  0.0006990041531870184
45  0.000694646402266827
46  0.0006910307645889419
47  0.0007918124250492787
48  0.0007699669760728367
49  0.0007850042712259613
50  0.0007735240355776444
51  0.0008333605652980768
52  0.0007914544977620185
53  0.0008254284036610573
54  0.0008578590784536057
55  0.0008597165395913466
56  0.0009350752655120189
57  0.0009355867078822116
58  0.0009413161534519229
59  0.001003045837043269
60  0.0009530084342740383
61  0.000981287851927885
62  0.000986143934318509
63  0.00096895140692548
64  0.0010671633388319713
65  0.0010884129846995196
66  0.0010974424039567304
67  0.0011198829067163459
68  0.0010649422789374995
69  0.0010909547135769227
70  0.0010858300892451934
71  0.00114890178018774
72  0.0011503018930817308
73  0.0012209814370937495
74  0.001264080502711538
75  0.0012453762294132222
76  0.0012725116258625
77  0.0012649334953990384
78  0.0012195748153341352
79  0.0013151443892213466
80  0.0013003322635283651
81  0.0013099768888799042
82  0.0013227992394807694
83  0.0013325137669168274
84  0.001356943212587259
85  0.0014541924819278852
86  0.0014094004314177883
87  0.0014273633669975969
88  0.0014393176087403859
89  0.0014372794673365393
90  0.0015051545220959143
91  0.0015432813234807683
92  0.0015832276965293275
93  0.001540622433288461
94  0.0016007491118125
95  0.0016195978358533654
96  0.0016447077023067317
97  0.0016350138695504803
98  0.0017352804136629807
99  0.001731106189370192
100 0.0017407015898704323
101 0.0017367582300937506
102 0.0018164239404875008
103 0.0017829769448653838
104 0.0018303930988165871
105 0.0017893320000211548
106 0.0018727349292259614
107 0.0018745909637668267
108 0.0018425366172147846
109 0.0019053739892581727
110 0.0018849885474855762
111 0.0018689524590103368
112 0.0019431807910961535
113 0.001951890517350962
114 0.0019308973497776446
115 0.0019990349471177894
116 0.002009245176572116
117 0.0020004240575882213
118 0.002020795320423557
119 0.0020148423748725963
120 0.002070277553975961
121 0.002112121992170673
122 0.002081609846093749
123 0.0020899822853341346
124 0.002214996736841347
125 0.002210968677028846
126 0.002204230691923077
127 0.0022059340675168264
128 0.002244672249610577
129 0.002243725570633895
130 0.002198417606970913
131 0.002326686848007212
132 0.002298981945014423
133 0.002412905193465384
134 0.0023317473012668287
135 0.0023255737818221145
136 0.0024042900543605767
137 0.0023814333208341345
138 0.002414946342495192
139 0.002451134140336538
140 0.002435468088014424
141 0.002541540709086779
142 0.0024759180712812523
143 0.002562872725209133
144 0.002554363054353367
145 0.002525350243064904
146 0.0026228594448966342
147 0.002640361090600963
148 0.0026968734518557683
149 0.002687729582449518
150 0.0026799173813848555
151 0.002751626483175481
152 0.0026916526068317286
153 0.002682602742860577
154 0.0027658840884567304
155 0.0028385319315024035
156 0.002733288245524039
157 0.002805041072350961
158 0.002798724552451201
159 0.00284738398885577
160 0.002833892571264423
161 0.0028506943730673084
162 0.0028578405825413463
163 0.0028141271324870197
164 0.0029047532288887
165 0.002916689246838943
166 0.003006111659274039
167 0.0030388357088942325
168 0.0030117903270181707
169 0.003023639132084136
170 0.0030182642660336535
171 0.0029788478969250015
172 0.003086049268993511
173 0.0030530940010240377
174 0.00309287048297596
175 0.0030892688902187473
176 0.0032070964353437493
177 0.0031308958387163454
178 0.003262165689711538
179 0.0032348496648947093
180 0.003334092027257212
181 0.0032702121678230764
182 0.0032887867663149036
183 0.00333782536743269
184 0.0033132179587812513
185 0.003400563164048078
186 0.003322215536028365
187 0.0033691419445264436
188 0.00340692471343654
189 0.003370118822997599
190 0.003414042435545674
191 0.003460621729710913
192 0.003487680921019232
193 0.0034814484875360595
194 0.003528280852358173
195 0.0035260558732403864
196 0.0035947047098653846
197 0.003583761358336538
198 0.003589446784643749
199 0.0035488957604610572
200 0.0036106514596322115
201 0.003633161542855769
202 0.003596668943564904
203 0.003621647520017789
204 0.0037260161142259616
205 0.0036873544761057684
206 0.003693311409786057
207 0.0037485618958747594
208 0.0037277801700697126
209 0.003731768419286058
210 0.0037200943660144225
211 0.0037368698886754786
212 0.0038266932486634626
213 0.003786905602120193
214 0.0038484308669038464
215 0.003837662506102065
216 0.003877989966946875
217 0.0038711451977908673
218 0.0039796825709810125
219 0.003955763375971154
220 0.003983664920576924
221 0.004019112007471154
222 0.003996646585913461
223 0.004061509550884613
224 0.004015245551199519
225 0.004009779120920672
226 0.004148229009661058
227 0.0040645974335312505
228 0.0041522345293678545
229 0.004216267765944711
230 0.004191517977733654
231 0.004280319721466346
232 0.004210795761447114
233 0.004258393462563462
234 0.004267925011272355
235 0.00427713419340625
236 0.004323331966394231
237 0.004361159201735935
238 0.004351708975694715
239 0.004359997178644953
240 0.00437384325853894
241 0.004375188742463941
242 0.004424559629495192
243 0.004461955226487498
244 0.004489655863850963
245 0.0045503420149230756
246 0.0045185560829999975
247 0.004506067166336778
248 0.004585396025798076
249 0.004530840472406252
250 0.0045934151490120215
251 0.004602146584228363
252 0.004643262102497593
253 0.004707265035608172
254 0.004766505116052884
255 0.004744165929896635
256 0.0047756718030625015
257 0.004802170611427885
258 0.004896239463478368
259 0.0048845448341901425
260 0.004845213594302884
261 0.004915008781204327
262 0.004838528640802884
263 0.0048121374747617796
264 0.004895357859576925
265 0.0048793476575266816
266 0.004958465852682693
267 0.005007965180538941
268 0.0049839032653341345
269 0.005068383734646637
270 0.00498556504900495
271 0.005014623260019232
272 0.005066327855785335
273 0.0050290740743365375
274 0.005152934708140861
275 0.005174238921781968
276 0.005123581464772355
277 0.005155969777822114
278 0.005169396608004327
279 0.00516497090489663
280 0.005145110646115385
281 0.005209611399110575
282 0.005163211771749997
283 0.005181044847507209
284 0.005281641245183894
285 0.005323840847189907
286 0.005230924322329326
287 0.005256136984014422
288 0.005374876757439424
289 0.0053137727444009615
290 0.005468482116127402
291 0.005453857539401205
292 0.005417081656274039
293 0.005393994523838937
294 0.005506909240446873
295 0.005449365350307692
296 0.005551215606367787
297 0.005505932791992786
298 0.0055918512302572145
299 0.005663100163579326
300 0.0056382443690432705
```

When I do

```html
f(x) = a/b*(1-exp(-b*x))
fit[1:300] f(x) "cn20x2012" using 1:2 via a,b
```

The curve fits perfectly. But when I try to fit the curve with

```html
a/b*(1-exp(-b*x/(3e-26))
```

I get the error message. Note that I've only added a constant to the exponential part of the function.

What can I do to fit the function with the constant 3e-26?

I'm using gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 8 on linux

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Reasonable initial values of `a` and `b` are helping the fitting algorithm to converge. However, if I plot your data, I see more or less linearly increasing datapoints. How do you want to fit  and exponential function to a linear dataset? You say you get a perfect fit, what are `a` and `b` in this case?

Comment: @theozh Sorry, I've entered the wrong function in the question. I edited the question with the correct function. The values of a and b are, respectively, 1.65837e-05 and -0.000846446. Note that I'm fitting only a small part of my curve, the complete data converges to 0.02.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding that constant makes the values of `exp(-b*x/(3.e-26)` so close to zero that the term `(1-exp(-b*x/(3e-26))` differs from `1` by less than the precision available for IEEE double precision floating point numbers.   So you are essentially fitting the function `g(x) = a/b`, which is a very poor fit to your data.

Since you already have a good fit using your original function f(x), perhaps you can explain what your goal is to change the function to something else?  What question are you trying to answer?

Comment: The data that I'm using is the average velocity of water molecules per time in a nanotube. The scale of y-axis is 10^5 m/s and the x-axis scale is 2.5e-13 s. So the function with the 3.e-26 constant that I'm trying to fit is the Taylor Series expansion of my model, at <v> approaching 0. So, in order to get the real values of b and a, I need to fit them in the function with 3.e-26, because that's the average water mass of the system.

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to try to fit a function whose parameters differ greatly in magnitude. It tends to make the problem ill-conditioned.  The usual way forward is to redefine the units being used for the fit and then convert them back to the "true" units afterwards.

Comment: @M.S.Barbosa NOOO! You don't need and you should not plug the values expressed in SI units only because they're SI units. You can assume any units, including nanometers or pounds or nautical miles, provided that you remember to scale the result accordingly. Your goal, as the fit master :-) , is to feed the gnuplot with the data that will make the wanted fit parameters as close to 1 as possible. This helps the underlying nonlinear fit engine very, very much. Of course, a fit parameter 0.01 or 100 is OK, but 1e13 is very bad.